# Compare three Dates in VBA

Tags: vba

Hi the code I had was working up util the new year and then I am thinking when it had to compare Dec 2016 with Jan 1 dates by using string and not date objects I had a problem. Is that correct or is it the logic I am using and is there a better way to do this?

```
Dim MAX_DATE  As String
MAX_DATE = Format(Now, "mmddyy")
Dim MIN_DATE As String
MIN_DATE = Format(Now - 20, "mmddyy")
If Not objP.CollDateFormat >= MIN_DATE And objP.CollDateFormat <= MAX_DATE Then
            Dim szMessage As String
            szMessage = "Collection Date is in the past"

    Exit Function
End If
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your question. You do not give the Dimensioning of the variable `objP` so we have no idea what that it linked to. The function is not complete(you have `Exit Function` which would indicate that this ia part of a Function. Also what library is `CollDateFormat` from?

Answer (score 1):

This will work to compare if a date is within a day from 20 days ago till today.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ff()

    Dim SomeDate As Date
    'Here you will insert the code for the actual date
    'or just change the SomeDate text in the if statement to you objP.CollDateFormat
    SomeDate = DateSerial(2016, 12, 30)



    Dim MAX_DATE  As Date
    MAX_DATE = Now
    Dim MIN_DATE As Date
    MIN_DATE = Now - TimeSerial(480, 0, 0) '480 hours is 20 days


    If Not SomeDate >= MIN_DATE And SomeDate <= MAX_DATE Then
        Dim szMessage As String
        szMessage = "Collection Date is in the past"
        'Exit Function
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I had problems with that when the min date was in Dec 2016 and the Max Date was in Jan is it related to the DateSerial object?

Comment: @THOMASJ.Mcdevitt The code i pasted works perfectly fine with the `SomeDate` being in December. If you run the code right now the `MAX_DATE` will be 2017/01/13 and the `MIN_DATE` will be 2016/12/24, which is exactly where you say the problem is. So I am not sure how to help further unless you explain better.